# Outlook security

Tags: security, ms-access, outlook

Is there any other way to get rid of this outlook security message? "A program is trying to automatically send e-mail on your behalf ... and so on" and it gives me an option to select Yes , No & Help.

Im currently developing an outlook automation app using Ms Access. Everytime I issue Send command this message popups, I tried using SendKeys "%s" but it does not work in Access 2007.

Is there any alternative solution for this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

You may wish to consider [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/)

From the blurb:

*Outlook Redemption works around limitations imposed by the Outlook Security Patch and Service Pack 2 of MS Office 98/2000 and Office 2002/2003/2007 (which include Security Patch) plus provides a number of objects and functions to work with properties and functionality not exposed through the Outlook object model.*

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft doesn't want scripts to be able to send email without the user's consent.  According to [KB 263084](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/263084), you can do one of the following (which avoid the scriptable interface or configure the system to supress the message):

- change some Exchange Server settings
- use CDO
- Use Extended MAPI
- use a COM add-in

I don't think any of the programming solutions is particularly simple, and applying changes to Exchange might not be a solution for you (especially if your application is supposed to work with Outlook clients that aren't in an Exchange environment, of course).

Comment: Changing Exchange settings is not an option, of course, in a standalone Access scenario (i.e., not running as an Exchange client).

Comment: CDO won't put a copy of the message in your Outlook sent messages folder. And extended MAPI is pretty difficult because of the way Microsoft patches the MAPI DLL -- there are some Outlook installations where it can never be used (usually where there are other email programs installed that install their own version of the MAPI DLL). I use Outlook Redemption and think it's just fine.

Comment: I agree that these options aren't great and certainly not simple.  I'm not familiar with Outlook Redemption, but took a quick look at the website - it looks like a potentially very nice option (it appears that it avoids the security message by essentially being a wrapper around Extended MAPI).

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this by relaying the message directly to an SMTP server, rather than using Outlook to relay the message. The security warning is there to stop people like you from sending messages from my account without my knowledge. Although you have good intentions, what you are writing is essentially virus-like (imagine if you could do this without the security prompt - spam-heaven!)

Comment: But if you go direct to SMTP, your Outlook sent mail folder won't include a copy of the message.

Comment: Exactly - we don't want applications or scripts to mess with our stuff. Imagine the possibilities that would exist if they allowed this type of script.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Redemption (others already adviced so I think you don't), you have another option that I can assure will be a lot more painful to implement. 
Basically what you will need to do is to create an Add-In instead an external program. The Add-In is able to do whatever you want to Outlook, without getting those messages.
You can probably make the Add-In act like a simple server - do things you want by receiving commands from the outside world (in case you can't do whatever you need to do from within Outlook).
Maybe you can lift a WCF service (IPC or Inter Process Communication, that works like a shared  memory between two processes).
Please note however that you will probably be better if you just use Redemption or just an Add-In.
Connecting Outlook with external process is a pain and it get's worse by the fact that the Outlook classes are not serializable. So basically you will need to do add Data Transport Objects for each and every class you need to access through your app.

Maybe if you resolve this one it will be a bit easier to implement but it is still a challenge.